# 400-500ms latency for simple Google Drive API file query from App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-drive-api

I'm running a Python 3.7 App Engine application in the Standard Environment. In general my time-to-first-byte for requests to this application range from 70-150ms when doing simple server-side rendering of text. My app runs in the `us-central` region, I'm testing from California.

I've been benchmarking requests to Google Drive API v3. I have a request which simply takes the drive file ID in the URL and returns some metadata about the file. The simplified code looks like:

```py
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

def get(file_id: str):
  credentials = oauth2.get_credentials()
  service = build("drive", "v3", cache_discovery=False, credentials=credentials)
  data = service.files().get(fileId=file_id, fields=",".join(FIELDS), supportsTeamDrives=True)
  return json.dumps(data)
```

My understanding is that this request should be making a single request to the Drive API. I'm seeing 400-500ms time-to-first-byte coming back from the server. That implies ~300ms to get data from the Drive API. This seems quite high to me.

My questions:
  * Is this kind of per-API-call latency common for Google Drive API
  * If this is not common, what is common?
  * What steps, if any, could I take to reduce the amount of time talking to the Drive API?